# Does creating an indexed computed column to check for nulls buy me anything?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, query-performance

I have nullable **DeletedDate** columns in my tables and whenever I write queries against these tables, I usually check to make sure `DeletedDate IS NULL`. My thought, was that if I create an indexed, persisted, computed column called **IsDeleted** that it might speed up my queries since it would only need to check a single bit value instead of however it indexes a series of dates.

```
[IsDeleted] AS (isnull(CONVERT([bit],case when [DeletedDate] IS NULL then (0) else (1) end),(0))) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
```

However, I looked at the execution plan and it appears that it still looks at the `DeletedDate` column (I think, I could be reading the plan wrong).

Does doing this buy be anything or is there different way to speed it up for queries that only care if the column is null or not?

Comment: What proportion of the records are deleted?

Comment: @GordonLinoff very few at the moment, but we haven't fully launched the app yet either

Comment: If that's a case, then you are looking for a performance improvement at a spot where you do not yet know that you have a performance problem to begin with.  That's the definition of premature optimization.  If you are asking for pure encyclopedic knowledge, I am afraid the best way to find an answer would be to try it yourself and measure it.

Comment: When you query your table, is the predicate on DeletedDate the *only* predicate, or just one of several?

Comment: @BenThul we're usually filtering on several columns in the queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An index on `DeletedDate` is (under most circumstances) only going to be useful if the vast majority of rows are not deleted.  Why?  Because if many records are deleted, then almost every data page is going to have both deleted and not-deleted records.

The index will not reduce the number of pages that need to be read.  Under such circumstances, scanning the data is usually faster.

One major exception to this is a clustered index where `DeletedDate` is the first column (or a deletion flag derived from that column).  In this case, the non-deleted records and the deleted records are almost always on *different* data pages.  So, if 5% of the records are deleted, you would only need to read about 5% of the data.

Of course, there is overhead with a clustered index.  When a record is deleted, the record actually gets moved in the databases -- causing multiple read/write operations and increasing the potential for fragmentation.  Whether or not using a clustered index is worth the extra overhead depends on how you are using the data, how frequently the updates occur, and other similar factors.

Comment: The vast majority of rows _are_ not deleted (null DeletedDate) so it's good to know that an index on DeletedDate will help when filtering on that column in my queries, but you didn't mention the computed column in your answer. Would an indexed computed column help at all?

Comment: A filtered index might. Much of this discussion depends on the actual query or queries you are using. And don't forget that nothing is free. You "pay" for the index when you modify rows. If you really want to know, there is only one answer - try it and compare the plans.